# Is there a way to tell a node stream (v0.10+) is paused?

Tags: node.js, stream

If I have a [stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), is there a way if I can tell if it is paused or not?

For example, could we use something `isPaused()` in my somewhat silly example below:

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
var pendingOtherOps = 0;
readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
  // about to do something that takes longer relative to our stream, may need to pause
  if (++pendingOtherOps >= MAX_PENDING) {
    stream.pause();
  }
  doOtherOp(data, function(err) {
    if (--pendingOtherOps === 0 && stream.isPaused()) {
      // ok we've got our other ops under control, lets turn stream back on
      stream.resume();
    }
  });
});
```

Right now I'm using a separate boolean I set when I pause/unpause and that seems redundant as the information is in the stream already.

Answer (score 0):

No, but:

1. you can run `stream.pause(); stream._paused = true` and set this flag yourself
2. you can run `stream.resume()` even if the stream is not paused, so the check is not needed in your particular case